# Java parse String into java Object

Tags: java, string, parsing, object

How can I parse a String like:

```
String m = "Material: chair\nPrice: 302.91\nCount: 5"
```

into a java Object:

```
public class Order {
    String material;
    String price;
    int count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Do you mean the left hand side value eg Material should automatically be considered and declared as variable name and right hand side value to be determined what type it is and assigned to the suitable type?

Comment: Simplest solution would be not inventing your own serialization format but use already existing one like JSON. So question is: why are you creating such mechanism on your own instead of using [already existing tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+parse+JSON)?

Comment: No I mean, how can I parse the values "chair", "302.91" and 5 into a single variable.

Comment: @Pshemo I know that would be easier, but it's my task to do it this way...

Comment: @csharper If you are not, for some reason, allowed to use an easy and obvious solution, that's the sort of thing you really should mention in your question.

Comment: You can split the string using [Java.String.split()](https://www.baeldung.com/string/split) and the use the setters of the class to set the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very trivial solution is:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String m = "Material: chair\nPrice: 302.91\nCount: 5";
        Order order = new Order(m);
        System.out.println(order.count);
        System.out.println(order.material);
        System.out.println(order.price);
    }
}


class Order {
    String material;
    String price;
    int count;
    public Order(String str){
        String[] parsedArr = str.split("\n");
        String materialStr = parsedArr[0];
        String priceStr = parsedArr[1];
        String countStr = parsedArr[2];
        this.material = materialStr.split(":")[1].trim();
        this.price = priceStr.split(":")[1].trim();
        this.count = Integer.parseInt(countStr.split(":")[1].trim());
    }
}
```

Just like other answers. I would recommend to use JSON instead of this kind of random String.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a class:

```
class Material{
    String material;
    String price;
    int count;
    public Material(String material, String price, int count){
         this.material = material;
         this.price = price;
         this.count = count;
    }
    // Override toString()? Comparable (compareTo())? 
}
```

```
class Foo{
    public static void main (String[] args){
         String S = "Wood 50 10";
         Material m = new Material();
         //m is now an object
         // You want to parse a string into an object. One way is java.util.Scanner
         // with methods like Scanner.nextInt() and Scanner.next();
         java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(S);
         m = new Material(sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.nextInt());

         String[] values = S.split(" "); // Split the string into and copy to an array
         m = new Material(values[0], values[1], Integer.parseInt(values[2]));
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the "parse a string" part of the question, which seems to be the actual point?

Comment: @another-dave fixed